# Как привязать событие к кнопке

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

```
<dx:ASPxGridView Width="100%" ID="gvWorkRequestPKA" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
  ClientInstanceName="gvWorkRequestPKA" KeyFieldName="req_id" DataSourceID="ODS_WorkRequestPKA"
  OnCustomCallback="gvWorkRequestPKA_CustomCallback" OnCustomErrorText="CustomErrorText"
  OnCustomButtonInitialize="gvPKR_CustomButtonInitialize" OnRowInserted="FocusRow"
  UpdateMethod="EditData" OnHtmlRowCreated="gvWorkRequestPKA_RowCreated">
  <ClientSideEvents CustomButtonClick="CustomButtonClickWR" CallbackError="function(s, e) { OnCallbackErr('msgUserWorkRequest', e); }" />
  <Columns>
      <dx:GridViewCommandColumn Name="CommandButtons" ButtonType="Image" VisibleIndex="0"
          ShowEditButton="true" ShowNewButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowClearFilterButton="true">
          <CustomButtons>
              <dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton ID="btnInsertMI" Text="Выбрать СИ к заявке"
                  Image-AlternateText="Добавить СИ к заявке" Image-SpriteProperties-CssClass="spr_folder_add12" />
                  <dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton ID="btnPrintReq" Text="Печать отчёта Заявки" Image-SpriteProperties-CssClass="spr_folder_doc12" />
          </CustomButtons>
```

У меня две кнопки CustomButton. Есть только одно событие у клиента ClientSideEvent -> CustomButtonClick. Вопрос в том, как создать второе событие для моей второй CustomButton?

Спасибо.

Comment: Создай еще один метод, и вызывай его в первом событии. Ты же спросил про два действия при одном клике на кнопку, который ты уже обрабатываешь, правильно?

Comment: На каждую кнопку - своё действие.  В ASP.NET есть ClientSideEvent и у него первый метод (CustomButtonClick). Второй метод куда привязать, вот вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

ASPxClientGridView предоставляет одно событие, но в параметры обработчика передается идентификатор нажатой кнопки, который позволяет определить какой обработчик нужно запустить.

Вот как это описано в [документации](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.Scripts.ASPxClientGridView.CustomButtonClick.event):

> The event parameter's ASPxClientGridViewCustomButtonEventArgs.buttonID
> property allows you to identify a button currently being clicked.
>
> Свойство buttonID объекта переданного в обработчик события в качестве
> параметра позволяет вам идентифицировать нажатую кнопку.

Вот как можно обработать это событие в коде:

```
function CustomButtonClick(s, e) {
  if (e.buttonID === 'btnInsertMI')
    Insert(e);
  else if (e.buttonID === 'btnPrintReq')
    Print(e);
}
```